# upload app to google play store custom track via fastlane supply

Tags: android, google-play-console, fastlane

I'm trying to upload an android apk to my self-created closed test track via "fastlane supply".

According to the merged pull request, it is possible (https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/12487)

supply (
track: 'alpha',
apk: "build / app / outputs / apk / release / app-release.apk"
)

I've already tried to write the name of the new track or custom on attribute track. But always get the error message that the track does not exist.

The upload generally works, it just doesn't load it into my desired track.

How do I have to define it so that the apk is loaded into the new track

I also tried to pause the alpha track so that only my new track is active, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Why don't you use `upload_to_play_store`?

Comment: What is your fastlane version?

Comment: Hey Akif, thanks for your answer. Currently I use version 2.188.0.

Supply should only be an alias for upload_to_play_store so it shouldn't make a difference which of the two I use. Both have the same entry in the documentation.

Even upload_to_play_store does not offer an attribute according to the documentation that allows me to determine which track of the closed tracks should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the attribute or the method, but the naming of the track.

I worked with upper and lower case, or with hyphens.

The following naming in fastlane and in Google Console works fine:

supply (
track: "alphaa",
apk: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
)

Answer (score 1):

Note also that the value of the `track` parameter is case-sensitive.